# can Teradata fastload load in chunks > 64K?

Tags: teradata

I Have few questions, which i was asked recently. Please help me with the answers.
1) In TD 14 can fastload load in chunks greater than 64K? Are there any other options for it.
2) Can we do a compression on varchar columns in TD 14.
3) How we force the optimizer to use the JOIN INDEX created?

Regards,
Amit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: No, this is both the default and the maximum size

Q2:Of course, COMPRESS on VarChar is supported since 13.10

Q3: There's no way to force it. But you can create a view with exactly the same SELECT, so you can utilize the JI like a Materialized View in FROM